# Replace with NaN by length of strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe with multiple columns with strings. How can I check the data in each cell and delete all them if the length of the string is less than 8?

in example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['123456789','0998733799','3245'], ['789793434','4','1221314234245']])
```

How can I delete the '3245' and '4' or even replace with NaN?

Comment: And which question you're looking for answering? The title/ this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pandas `DataFrame` is possible remove row(s) or column(s), removing some cells is not possible. So here is solution for replace to `NaN`s by [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) for length for each column with [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) for set to default value `NaN`:

```
df1 = df1.mask(df1.apply(lambda x: x.str.len().lt(8)))

#if possible some values are integers
df1 = df1.mask(df1.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.len().lt(8)))
print (df1)
           0           1              2
0  123456789  0998733799            NaN
1  789793434         NaN  1221314234245
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below line of code

```
df = df.mask(df.apply(lambda x: x.str.len().lt(8)))
```